# Laravel ui login error after installation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am trying to login using auth after laravel ui installation but I get an error like this.

Error:

```
419 Page Expired
```

There is a "users" table in the database and there are required columns such as "name, password, e-mail".

```
App/config/session.php
```

For example, I went to the section above and checked the values.

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
```

I tried to find a solution by adding "false" later, but it didn't work. Can you help me? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: put @csrf after form

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Which form will I add?

Comment: You get this error after submit the form?

Comment: Yes and I checked I added after @csrf form in login.blade.php

Comment: does it solve your problem

Comment: Sorry it does not solve

Comment: Have you made any modifications to the login form or to the way laravel is handling sessions? Do you see the account you are trying to log in as in the database?

Comment: No I have not made any changes and the user appears to be attached to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by installing laravel valet and running the project there.